# How to position two forms next to each other centered over an image

Tags: html, css, forms

I am pulling my hair out over the correct way to position two forms using html and css. I have tried both float and display:inline-block but only managed to get half of it working using one of the methods.

My target is to have the two forms display next to each other centered in a DIV that is only 70% of the page and each form takes up 50% of the available space. Both forms need to have a minimum width and should be pushed into separate lines if there isn't enough space to display both next to each other (i.e. when displaying the page on a phone in portrait mode)

If I float the two DIVs containing the forms they are displayed side by side but are not centered correctly (as they float either left or right and I need to set the size of each DIV to 40% or they don't fit next to each other).
If I use display:inline-block the DIVs are in the correct size and centered but are in two separate lines and not next to each other.

Here is the current code using display: inline-block

```css
#background {
  background-image: url(pic.jpg);
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#form1 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#form2 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <div id="form1">
      <form>some form code here</form>
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
      <form>some form code here</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why are the forms on different lines when using display:inline-block ?

Comment: FYI: you haven't escaped your "form-wrapper" ID: `<div id="form-wrapper>`

Comment: close the id :-), <div id="form-wrapper> ==> <div id="form-wrapper">

Comment: not closing the ID is a typo I made when trying to simplify the code for stackoverflow, it is closed on the site and is not causing the problem

Answer (score 5):

You might be having trouble getting the two `inline-block` elements next to each other because 50% times two plus the white space between the elements is greater than 100% of the container. Therefore, the second element doesn't have enough space and wraps to the next line.

`inline-block` elements will respect white space in the HTML code. The white space between the two elements is demonstrated below:

```css
#background {
  background-image: url(pic.jpg);
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#form1 {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
#form2 {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <div id="form1">
      <form>some form code here</form>
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
      <form>some form code here</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, one solution to your issue is to remove the white space, as shown below.

I have also given each element a minimum width so that they wrap to separate lines when the window is below a specified width. To see this action, click the "Full page" button in the upper right corner and resize your browser window.

```css
#background {
  background-image: url(pic.jpg);
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#form1 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width:200px;
}
#form2 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <div id="form1">
      <form>some form code here</form>
    </div><div id="form2">
      <form>some form code here</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing all whitespace and/or setting the width of the forms to less than 50% also has no impact, the forms stay in separate lines

Comment: The solution you have regarded is not working properly when the window width is small, i.e the two forms does not fill two lines. [Checkout this demo](http://jsbin.com/qiraxo/1/)

Comment: @chipotle My demo shows the two elements on the same line. Perhaps your actual context differs from the code you've posted. If so, please edit your question to include the relevant code and illustrate the issue you're having.

Comment: seems to work just fine to me, and exactly what I would propose. http://jsfiddle.net/tsv9as02/

Comment: @Pevara It does not work as supposed, try to minify the output window.

Comment: Yes it is, the last update works fine. The `min-width` got it.

Comment: Yep, the examples seem to work just fine so I must have another issue in my code. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I had another look at the page and one of the forms (generated by a Wordpress plugin I use) seems to be behaving incorrectly. It seems to cover the whole width of the page and has display: block; set which seems to be coming from the user agent stylesheet. I need to do some more digging.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` in your wrapper:

```
#form-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
}
```

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/migaba/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your input! After looking at this issue for two days I was questioning basically anything but your examples showed that my original idea for the css using display: inline-block worked well.

The example at http://jsbin.com/qiraxo/2/ is exactly what I am looking for.

After digging some more I realized that one of my forms didn't work and even copying the working form in a second time didn't change the behaviour. So some more digging and I found the issue: a typo in a DIV declaration....

Thanks again and have a good evening.